# Digital Transactions question -- enabling live mode

Tags: actions-on-google

If you have digital transactions setup and your app is published then I am guessing that automatically makes it live, is that right?

I know there is an option in the console simulator "All transactions are not sandboxed. It will charge your card and execute an order."  it allows you to turn sandboxing on and off, does this affect the published version of the game?

Comment: It should not have an effect, since in the simulator you'd be creating a new draft version of your Action with settings that are separate from the existing public version.

Comment: Does that mean if you published the app with live mode disabled it would be a problem in the published app?  Certainly Google wouldn't allow a live mode disabled transaction app to be published I'm guessing.

Comment: Each version that is submitted publicly goes through a review. This may be something that is checked in a review.

Answer (score 0):

When I did an alpha version of my app (using digital transactions) those were actually live transactions as well--which I did not expect. It's not clear to me if I could have selected those to be sandboxed.